# 500 after install - Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist

Tags: magento2, installation, command-line

I installed Magento2 successfully through the commandline, but when i try to access the website, i get a Server Error 500.

The server runs on Ubuntu 14.04

I have no idea what is wrong, or what i am doing wrong.
I used a script to install Magento2 so i expect it to be correct

PHP Errors:

> [Wed Mar 02 17:03:18.718890 2016] [:error] [pid 2292] [client 192.168.56.1:62335] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist' in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#5 /var/ww in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 19

and this multiple times

> [Wed Mar 02 17:03:18.718739 2016] [:error] [pid 2292] [client 192.168.56.1:62335] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/var/generation:/var/www/html/lib/internal:/var/www/html/var/generation:/var/www/html/lib/internal:/var/www/html/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php on line 158

and

> [Wed Mar 02 17:03:18.718377 2016] [:error] [pid 2292] [client 192.168.56.1:62335] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/var/generation/Magento//Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/var/generation:/var/www/html/lib/internal:/var/www/html/var/generation:/var/www/html/lib/internal:/var/www/html/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 412

Also, this is the core_config_data from the magento database

[image]

Any idea what i could try?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento2/ 
chmod 777 -R var generated app/etc
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
```

and

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
```

If you're using `Docker`, you need to restart the containers.

Comment: worked for me and i had missing other class that wasn't mentioned

Comment: chmod 777 is a very bad idea and allows others to hack your server easily especially on shared hosting! fix the users instead

Answer (score 10):

Delete composer autoload (`vendor/autoload.php`) as suggested by @JELLEJ and type `composer install` in magento root folder to recreate it.

It worked for me on Magento 2.3.5-p1 (but should work in other versions).

Comment: I tried all the other suggestions on this page and this was the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: didn't work for other versions

Comment: The accepted answer is true, but this one too depending on the situation. Worked for me.

Comment: worked for me! thx!

Answer (score 2):

several classes in Magento2 are generated dynamically. Except you are in Developer mode, this does not happen automatically.

To activate the developer Mode, you have to uncomment the Line in the beginning of your .htaccess file.

For production and default mode you have to execute the command `bin/magento setup:di:compile` from your magento root to generate the classes

Comment: After installing Magento2, and using the command `setup:di:compile` I still get the Server Error 500, and i noticed that i cannot show or set modes in magento using the `deploy:mode:show` and `deploy:mode:set`
 command.

Comment: @Maarten, check your server logs

Comment: Sometimes for me it helps to delete the vendor/autoload.php file

Comment: @black, I don't say it is not needed. I say sometimes it helps removing it and doing the composer install again.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing below one-time steps ideally for the local setup, especially stand-alone Magento setups.

*Commands mainly for Ubuntu-based.*

1. Use `whoami` command to find out which user is currently on. Mostly you will get non-root users.

```
someotheruser@core:/var/www/html$ whoami
```

Should output as below:

```
someotheruser
```

2. Optional: Below one only requires if you are on non `root`
   Switch to non-root user(`magento`).

```
someotheruser@core:/var/www/html$ sudo -u magento /bin/bash
```

3. Run below command to get the current user, should give ***magento*** as we have changed the user to ***magento***

```
magento@core:/var/www/html$ echo "$USER"
```

4. Give current user(***magento***) to www-data group as a secondary user

```
magento@core:/var/www/html$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
```

5. Change ownership to directory

```
magento@core:/var/www/html$ sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/html/
```

Ownership can be given to the `someotheruser` user as well. Make sure to give to non-root users.

- Worked well for me to resolve this error on various installations Magento 2.3.x to Magento 2.4.x.
- This can resolve the above error if you are facing the same every time after running some `bin/magento` commands especially `setup:upgrade` or `setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are facing this issue whilst the permission set correctly already and mainly use RHEL/CentOS, you may be facing issues with files security context `SElinux`, as per the docs [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/security.html), you may need to change the security context due to SElinux configuration on your root directory as following:

1-

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <magento_root>/app/etc
```

2-

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <magento_root>/var
```

3-

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <magento_root>/pub/media
```

4-

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <magento_root>/pub/static
```

5-

```
chcon -R --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t <magento_root>/generated
```

This will make SElinux allow access from nginx/apache to your magento files.

Answer (score 0):

- First reason could be you have installed PHP 8 and Magento2 is not compatible with it yet. So to resolve this, you need to use PHP 7.4.
- Other reason we need to find with below steps:

  - Open the bootstrap.php file present in the app folder of magento directory.
  - Remove # from the beginning of the line
    #ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);
  - Save the file and refresh your browser to see the exact issue.

Happy Learning !!
Thank You !!