# Magento 2.2 Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: error

Tags: magento2, module, error

i created a new module, after runing this command

> php bin/magento module:enable myFirstModule

i am getting this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManage in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php on line 19

i have clear all of my cache and also used upgrade command.
but in CMD the results are...[image: CMD Results]

what would be the reason of this?[image]
i also removed those module files but still there is error.

Comment: You can supply your module code?

Comment: One can give a try on this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351498/34579

Comment: That seems a Windows environment... You are brave 

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2 module names are the case sensitive in your case check the name of the modules you defined in namespaces and other places like module.xml or registration.php